# I need some free softwares to make c# application setup with database

Tags: c#, sql, download-manager

I have created a c# windows application which is simple and has simple sql database, I use SSMS to manage my database, but now is time to create a setup because I want my app to be ready to use for my "clients", but I can't find free softwear which can make my installation setup with database and it is important to be able to create auto-updater because I am beginner and I am sure that after the realise there will be a lot of bugs also I want to add new features. I have tried Advanced Installer but I can't find free version, because it is very expensive, I have tried also INNO setup but I can't find way to update my apps. So please give me some advices for my problem what can I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://wixtoolset.org/ to create your installer. It allows you to create the update packages. After you have your set up project created with wix, you rarely have to update the wix project's XMLs/configuration. Creating an update package is to increase the version number, while keeping the upgrade guid the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inno Setup, a free tool that creates an exe setup file from the directory of your project.

You can also use Advanced Installer, which is not free but will give you more advanced stuff. For example you can specify the minimum .NET version that should be installed before installing.

Now concerning the database, I think it will be better to switch to portable databases like MS Access or SQLite, and just put the file alongside other files. This way the user will not have to install anything, which will increase user experience.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But do you know how to create Inno setup auto updater because I have read a lot and a lot of people say that there is no way to do this with inno. Thank you again!